# ¿Como obtener el valor de una celda de un DataGrid?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf

Quiero obtener el valor de la celda **idUsuario** que tiene la siguiente configuracion realizado con **Visual Studio 2017** en una ventana **(WPF)**

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=idUsuario}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}"  Header="idUsuario" HeaderStringFormat="idUsuario" Visibility="Hidden"/>
```

Ya que el usuario no tiene por que ver el **id** lo puse oculto, el usuario selecciona una fila que tiene los datos de registro.
Mediante un boton se obtendra el **id** de ese registro para usarlo despues.

el codigo del llenado es el siguiente realizado con **C#**

```
public void llenadoDataGrid()
    {
        String consulta = "select idUsuario,Nombre,ApellidoP ,ApellidoM ,Sexo,Telefono,Edad,Puesto from usuarios;";
        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(consulta, new BaseDeDatos().obtenerConexion());
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
        DataTableCollection collection = ds.Tables;
        DataTable table = collection[0];

        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            var data = new PruebaDeLLenadoDataGrid {idUsuario = row["idUsuario"].ToString(), Nombre = row["Nombre"].ToString(),
                ApellidoP = row["ApellidoP"].ToString(), ApellidoM = row["ApellidoM"].ToString(),
                Sexo = row["Sexo"].ToString(), Telefono = row["Telefono"].ToString(),
                Edad = row["Edad"].ToString(), Puesto = row["Puesto"].ToString() };
            dataGridUsuarios.Items.Add(data);
        }
    }
```

La otra clase que utilizo llamada **PruebaDeLLenadoDataGrid**
tiene lo siguiente

```
lass PruebaDeLLenadoDataGrid
{
    public String idUsuario { get; set; }
    public String Nombre { get; set; }
    public String ApellidoP { get; set; }
    public String ApellidoM { get; set; }
    public String Sexo { get; set; }
    public String Telefono { get; set; }
    public String Edad { get; set; }
    public String Puesto { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

como estuve ayudándote en el transcurso de este problema continuare con ello.

Lo puedes obtener de varias maneras.

1.- Con el evento **keyUp**: lo puedes agregar en las propiedades de funciones de tu dataGrid:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El cual te auto creara una función como esta:

```
private void dataGridUsuarios_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
}
```

En el cual agregas su contenido, que segun tu modelo debe de ir de la siguiente manera:

```
switch (e.Key)
{
    case Key.Down:
    case Key.Up:
    PruebaDeLLenadoDataGrid dato= (PruebaDeLLenadoDataGrid)dataGridUsuarios.SelectedItem;
    MessageBox.Show("El id es:"+dato.idUsuario+" y el nombre es:"+dato.Nombre);
}
```

Esta funcion captura la fila seleccionada con las teclas arriba y abajo.

2.- con el evento **MouseLeftButtonUp** :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El cual de la misma forma que el anterior te creara una funcion, y agregas la logica. Este seria tu funcion completa:

```
private void dataGridUsuarios_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    PruebaDeLLenadoDataGrid dato= (PruebaDeLLenadoDataGrid)dataGridUsuarios.SelectedItem;
    MessageBox.Show("El id es:"+dato.idUsuario+" y el nombre es:"+dato.Nombre);
}
```

Este evento se activara al hacer click izquierdo en una fila.

En lo personal siempre implemento ambas,te recomiendo hacer lo mismo para no tener fallas, ademas de que le daras mas facilidad de uso al usuario final.

Comment: A funcionado perfecto muchas gracias, y si es continuacion de las demas preguntas solo en el switch agrege el **break** pero supongo que eso ya es algo basico.. Muchas gracias ya que es un lenguaje nuevo para mi estoy aprendiendo todo lo que se pueda.. pero al tener algunas similitudes con **java**  es un popco mas facil

Comment: Basicamente el break es inecesario ya que no tenemos mas **case** por debajo de este.

Comment: En mi caso no me lo permite.. si lo dejo sin **break** practicamente me marca error y no me permite continuar con dicho error.. en **java** si que funciona sin **break** a qui parece que no

Answer (score 1):

saludos en tu caso puedes hacer lo siguiente para obtener el usuario seleccionado en el DataGrid.

```
var seleccionado = dataGridUsuarios.SelectedCells[0].Item as PruebaDeLLenadoDataGrid;
```

Teniendo el usuario ya puedes tener el valor de cada propiedad por ejemplo

```
string idUsuario = PruebaDeLLenadoDataGrid.IdUsuario;
```

Trata de ver si asi puedes soluccionarlo.